How to Implement Role-Based Access to Custom Pages in a WordPress Plugin?
I am developing a WordPress plugin for a fitness community site that includes custom pages for managing nutrition and exercise logs. The plugin needs to restrict access to certain pages based on user roles.
Specifically:
Administrators should have full access to all plugin pages, including configuration settings and user management.
Trainers should be able to access and edit all member logs but not see configuration settings.
Members should only see their personal logs and no one else's.
I have used the current_user_can() function in the past for simpler access control, but this project might benefit from a more scalable approach.
Are there any particular hooks or functions that are well-suited for managing access controls on custom plugin pages?
